# Mongodb how to find all subdocuments that match a criteria

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to query all documents that meet a criteria in a subdocument/object.

How do a create a query that finds all matching subdocuments/objects?

Here's the collection:

```
document = { _id: ObjectId("..."),
            product: "ABC", 
            actions: [
                {
                    customer: "Foo",
                    status: "SOLD"
                },
                {
                    customer: "Bar",
                    status: "NOT SOLD"
                },
                {
                    customer: "John", 
                    status: "SOLD"
                },
                {
                    customer: "Doe", 
                    status: "WAITING"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Here's my code that returns all documents which have one actions.status = SOLD but it only returns the first subdocument in actions.

```
    def query(collection):
        """
        Find all products that have been sold to one or more customers
        """
        query = {"actions.status":"SOLD"}
        options = {"product":1, "actions.$":1}

        res = collection.find(query, options)
```

The output I want is all products and all the customers that have status = SOLD but my query only returns the first customer which have status = SOLD.

So what I want is

```
    document = { _id: ObjectId("..."),
            product: "ABC", 
            actions: [
                {
                    customer: "Foo",
                    status: "SOLD"
                }, 
                {
                    customer: "John", 
                    status: "SOLD"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            product:1,
            actions: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$actions",
                    as: "act",
                    cond:  { $eq: ["$$act.status", 'SOLD' ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cadfaff3d124a151f633af7"),
    "product" : "ABC",
    "actions" : [
        {
            "customer" : "Foo",
            "status" : "SOLD"
        },
        {
            "customer" : "John",
            "status" : "SOLD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no way of "filtering" this in a `standard query` .The only tools MongoDB actually has to do this level of `manipulation is with the aggregation framework`.